# конвертировать несколько чисел в одно

Tags: числа

Всем добрый день! Есть набор чисел:

```
8029269
3970250
7524479
6744955
1823612
```

Как объединить все эти числа в одно число(например с помощью каких-то манипуляций с числами в двоичной системе счисления или что-то ещё) с возможностью восстановления всех этих чисел с полученного результата?

Comment: просто склеить как строки, а потом резать по 7 десятичных цифр

Comment: Если склеить строки, то получится число "80292693970250752447967449551823612", а нужно попробывать получить число меньше чем это.

Comment: тогда это невозможно. для конкретно этих чисел может что то и можно придумать. но для чуть чуть других чисел придуманный метод может не подойти. можно попробовать пойти по пути архивации повторяющихся битовых цепочек, но опять же запросто найдутся числа для которых придуманный алгоритм даст увеличение длины, а не сокращение

Comment: Набор чисел фиксированный?

Comment: Да, число не больше "9999999". Хотелось бы рассмотреть любой способ, который подойдёт даже не для всех чисел, вдруг сгодится, да и для самообразования будет плюсом)

Comment: Что вообще идей никаких, кроме как от бестолкового склеивания строк и последующим банальным разбиванием их по 7 цифр?